# import data from HBase insert to another table using Pig UDF

Tags: python-2.7, hbase, apache-pig

I'm using Pig UDFs in python to read data from HBase table then process and parse it, to finally insert it into another HBase table. But I'm facing some issues.

- Pig's map is equivalent to Python's dictionary;
- My Python script take as input (rowkey, some_mapped_values), and
  return two strings "key" and "content", and the
  @outputSchema('tuple:(rowkey:chararray, some_values:chararray)');
- The core of my Python takes a rowkey, parse it, and transform it into
  another rowkey, and transform the mapped data into another string, to
  return variables (key,content);

But when I try to insert those new values into another HBase table, I have faced two problems:

1. Processing is well done, but the script insert "new_rowkey+content" as a rowkey and leaves the cell empty;
2. Second problem, is how do I specify the new column family to insert
   in ?

here is a snippet of my Pig script:

```
register 'parser.py' using org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine as myParser;

data = LOAD 'hbase://source' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('values:*', '-loadKey true') AS
(rowkey:chararray, curves:map[]);


data_1 = FOREACH data GENERATE myParser.table_to_xml(rowkey,curves);


STORE data_1 INTO 'hbase://destination' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('a_column_family:curves:*');
```

and my Python script take as input (rowkey,curves)

```
@outputSchema('tuple:(rowkey:chararray, curves:chararray)')
def table_to_xml(rowkey,curves):
    key = some_processing_which_is_correct

    for k in curves: 
        content = some_processing_which_is_also_correct
    return (key,content)
```

Comment: what do you get when you dump data_1 is it something like ((rowkey,content)) or just (rowkey,content)

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana after dump I get something like : (old_rowkey,(new_rowkey , content ) )

Comment: and inside content I get a lot of values like : array( 'b' , [ <8 int elements> ] )

Comment: that is the problem  (old_rowkey,(new_rowkey , content ) )  (new_rowkey , content ) is concidered as the content. data_1 should ideally have (key,content)